# How to set CSS rule for a DIV in a LI of class UL?

Tags: html, css, class

I have a list of results from a query. That list will be displayed like that:

```
<ul class="result">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now I would like to add something like a layer like `li:before` or a DIV into `li`.

So I thought it would possible to do it like that:

```
<ul class="result">
    <li><div id="a"></div></li>
    <li><div id="a"></div></li>
    <li><div id="a"></div></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The problem is that I can not set any CSS rule for this?

I tried:

```
.wrapper #header #navline #searchbar .dropdown .result li#a{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 10px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

as well as

```
.wrapper #header #navline #searchbar .dropdown .result li #a{...}
```

and just

```
.wrapper #header #navline #searchbar .dropdown .result #a{...}
```

but nothing worked. Is there a mistake in my thoughts or is it not possible to add a `DIV` into `li`'s?

Comment: Have you tried it without all the stuff before .result? Or ul . result li #count

Comment: #count is a typo. i updated it already. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your markup as follows (because IDs should be unique, you can use classnames instead):

```
<ul class="result">
    <li><div class="a"></div></li>
    <li><div class="a"></div></li>
    <li><div class="a"></div></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Your CSS selector should then look like this:

```
.wrapper #header #navline #searchbar .dropdown .result li .a {

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a better way that only uses one div?

Answer (score 10):

A) Use unique `ID`s for you elements

B) Your CSS selectors are way too complicated

C) It should be `.result li #a` because `.result li#a` would mean thats the `li`s have the ID

D) When you use classes for the `div` such as:

```
<ul class="result">
    <li><div class="aDiv"></div></li>
    <li><div class="aDiv"></div></li>
    <li><div class="aDiv"></div></li>
    <li><div class="aDiv"></div></li>
</ul>
```

your selector should look like this

```
.result li .aDiv {
    /* CSS styles */
}
```

or, if necessary (you only want to tagret `<ul class="result">` inside a specific `element#someId`), you can use a little bit more complicated selector:

```
#someId .result li .aDiv {
    /* CSS styles */
}
```

however, chaining ID selectors is redundant:

```
#someId #someOtherId #finallyThere .result li .aDiv {
    /* CSS styles */
}
```

because, as mentioned before, IDs are **unique**

Comment: You should perhaps mention the specificity of `#someID .result li .aDiv` vs. `.result li .aDiv`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a better way that only uses a single div?

Answer (score 1):

instead of: `<li><div id="a"></div></li>`  use `<li><div class="a"></div></li>` and then you only thing you should do is: .result li{style this thing}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given all of the html that encloses the above, so this may need further refinement for your requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul.result li div#a{ color: red; }
        ul.result li div#b{ color: green; }
        ul.result li div#c{ color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="result">
        <li><div id="a">This is red</div></li>
        <li><div id="b">This is green</div></li>
        <li><div id="c">This is blue</div></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the same id for every div. So, you have to add class.